# Create a copy of MFT using DD and convert to CSV?

Tags: filesystem, ntfs

I am looking for a way to save a copy of the NTFS file system MFT to analyze the dates of last access to the files and also the complete list of files.
I have thought about the use of DD to avoid having to mount the unit and not modify the date of the last access to the MFT (this I need to know when the disc was last used).

If possible I would also like to see the list of deleted files or be able to filter it by means of a command.

Is it possible to do this? Can this method be more practical to investigate the dates of last access or is it better for me to make a complete copy of the disk and analyze it with some software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search leads to this:

You will need a **sleuthkit** tool, and **analyzeMFT** pip module

```
sudo apt install sleuthkit
sudo pip install analyzeMFT # install globally
```

This will give us the *mmls* (not really needed) and *icat* tool

Let assume that `/dev/sdx` is your disk. But you can adapt the command to run this on an image.

```
sudo mmls /dev/sdx
```

which will gives you the offset of the NTFS partition, say 1107968

Then,

```
sudo icat -o 1107968 /dev/sdx 0 > mft.raw
```

Then,

```
sudo analyzeMFT.py -f mft.raw -o mftanalyzed.csv
```

In case you have a **disk image of your NTFS partition**, this would be enough

```
icat -o 0 image.raw 0 > mft.raw
analyzeMFT.py -f mft.raw -o mftanalyzed.csv
```

I guess

[Source](https://www.andreafortuna.org/dfir/how-to-extract-data-and-timeline-from-master-file-table-on-ntfs-filesystem/)

Comment: If you think this is the answer to your question, please, mark it as such by tcbking the mark. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do this?

Sure, you can do this with [RecuperaBit](https://github.com/Lazza/RecuperaBit). As a disclaimer, I shall clarify that *I am the developer.*

After you've let it scan the drive or a disk image, type `recoverable` to get a list of partitions, including deleted ones that can be reconstructed. Let's say your partition has id `0` you can then issue:

```
csv 0 results.csv
```

For a CSV file, or:

```
bodyfile 0 results.body
```

For a [body file](https://wiki.sleuthkit.org/index.php?title=Body_file) which is compatible with `mactime`.